# changing value of QueryString

Tags: vb.net, href, visual-studio-2003, request.querystring

I got the error in Query String. My project was written by ms visual studio 2003. Please see my code below

```
<a target="_blank" href="./PageOne.aspx?Customer=NAME1 + NAME2 + NAME3 PARA TEST">NAME1 + NAME2 + NAME3 PARA TEST</a>
```

System tried to get the customer value at PageOne like below

```
Request.QueryString("Customer").ToString
```

The value is

```
NAME1   NAME2   NAME3 PARA TEST
```

**The plus sign** is replaced by space. Please share me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

URL's are subject to [URL encoding and decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding).  And unfortunately for your URL, in this encoding scheme a `+` represents a literal space.  You can fix this issue by [encoding](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Encode.aspx) the URL yourself so that the browser knows that you have literal `+` signs in your parameter that should be preserved, like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="./PageOne.aspx?Customer=NAME1+%2b+NAME2+%2b+NAME3+PARA+TEST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Url decoding in the URL - More info here - [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)